# Start every or specified applications maximized in budgie?

Tags: budgie

How can I start every or specified applications maximized in budgie (with kupfer)?

Answer (score 0):

The user unfortunately has little control on how an application is started. It is not possible to start a program along with instructions on how the window should be sized.

In many cases, the application remembers its window state. Thus, if you start Firefox, maximize it and then close it, the next time, Firefox will start maximized. It works similar for the File manager, Editor, ...

In some cases, applications may provide command line options to control the window size on startup. In other cases, a window size on start-up may be stored in a config file.

Finally, utilities such as devilspie and devilspie2 allow to define rules for specific windows. Thus, they allow to maximize a window automatically as it is created (such as when the application is first started, or a new window is created).